# Why virtualized ListBox requests old items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have my own DefferedList:IList class. I overrode

> Count, IndexOf, this[]

members and put

> Debug.WriteLine("Get " + index);

into this[int index].

Then I binded instance of this class to ListBox.ItemSource.

Everything is fine but UI virtualization works a bit strange for me. I run application. ListBox is populated by first 17 items (from 0 to 17). Then I jump to 200th item

```
TheList.ScrollIntoView(Item200);
```

ListBox requests 200th item, then again items from 0 to 16 and finally 184-209.

So why does it request again 0-16 items while they are not visible anymore? It affects performance of my data virtualization very badly.

How to avoid it?

Comment: The code link you provided is a bit complex to understand ... Did you consult with the owner of the code?

Comment: have you set `VirtualizationMode = Recycling`? BTW, How you know which items was requested whilst scrolling?

Comment: I made my question a bit more clear. Changing VirtualizationMode didn't help

Comment: Can you modify your data virtualization so that requesting items that were already requested does not perform any operation?

Comment: Have you considered using a different control than a listbox? For large numbers of items it might just not be a good user experience. Maybe a LongListSelector?

Comment: I can modify data virtualization but it may involve a lot of work. ListBox gives me very good user experience. But if this issue isn't resolvable, then I will definitely try LongListSelector.

Answer (score 0):

I have some really bad experience with numerous hours wasted in productivity over using custom virtualization of lists used in a standard ListBox. I would advise against using custom lists and use an ObservableCollection instead. I think ListBox was probably mostly tested with an ObservableCollection and any tricks you try to make to avoid populating the entire list are likely to backfire since the ListBox is not really as flexible as you would expect based on the fact that ItemsSource is just an IEnumerable. Actually based on that expectation - you could assume that it needs to enumerate all items between 0 and 200 if you want to display item 200.

If you have a few hundred items in a list - you might want to simplify the data model for displaying them, so you populate an ObservableCollection with all the items from the beginning and only load the item data when the contents of the items are requested and not already available. If that is too much - you could add a small delay before loading the data and check if the collection item view is visible on screen after that delay before you start loading.

Another thing that is supposedly helpful is if your ItemTemplate is of predefined dimensions.

Comment: Nope, virtualized ListBox doesn't enumerate items from 0 to 200 if I request 200th. My test showed it. I tried INotifyCollectionChanged but behavior was the same. Seems it doesn't matter what you have as underlying storage (IList, ObservableCollection or INotifyCollectionChanged)